# SVG Image layering

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently working on a mobile design for my website.
On my page I have an image which is currently an SVG and here's why:
There is a text overlay over the image to which when exported as a PNG both the quality is lost.
I tried exporting the text as an SVG and layering it over the png image, this didnt work either.
When i am in Google Chrome's dev tools (iPhone 5 selected) the SVG image loads perfectly fine - I really dont know what is going on, I feel I have tried every trick to my knowledge.
Is there a way around it?

You can view my page I am working on [here](http://thairapyexeter.co.uk/about.html) but dont forget to view it on iPhone 5 using the Dev tools

Comment: Why not just use the image for the background of an element and layer text or a separate image on top?

Comment: What I found is that they didnt layer

Comment: Ever heard of the z-index CSS property? How did you try to position them?

Comment: Yes, z-index was the first thing on the list. I think it may be a little more technical than this

Comment: I mean using the `background-image` property.  Then you can make it adapt to the width and height using `background-size` and two pngs or one png with actual text on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a snippet for you which does more or less what you say.  I have an SVG on top of an image.

The code is easy:

```
<div class="bg-img">
    <svg height="150" width="500">
      <ellipse cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:purple" />
      <ellipse cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:lime" />
      <ellipse cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15" style="fill:yellow" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. 
    </svg>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.bg-img {
    background:transparent url(https://shanshad1.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/c1d53-its_magic.jpg?w=383&h=469) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:40px;
    min-height:400px;
}
```

Although you only need background-size and background to get the effect.  The other styles just emphasize the result...

```css
.bg-img {
    background:transparent url(https://shanshad1.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/c1d53-its_magic.jpg?w=383&h=469) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:40px;
    min-height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
    <svg height="150" width="500">
      <ellipse cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:purple" />
      <ellipse cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:lime" />
      <ellipse cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15" style="fill:yellow" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. 
    </svg>
</div>
```